# Python program that replaces each word in a sentence with a synonym

Tags: python

Basically what I want to do is create a program that takes in a sentence/paragraph as user input, looks up a synonym for each word, and replaces the word with the synonym. The program I've created so far to do this runs perfectly, but there are some kinks/human errors/logic errors. Here's what I've got right now:

```
response=input("Enter what you want to thesaurize")
orig=response #puts user input into a string
num=orig.count(" ")+1 #finds number of words in the sentence
orig=orig.split(" ") #turns the sentence into a list of its words
new=[] #creates a new list to put the new words in, in case I'd want to go back to the original sentence for any reason
for i in range (num):
        if orig[i] not in badWords: #makes sure that the word is not a no-synonym word like "the" or "be"
            new.insert(i, myFuncs.replace(orig[i])) #the replace function (which I put in a separate module for neatness purposes) looks up the word on thesaurus.com and replaces it with a synonym
        else:
            new.insert(i, orig[i]) #If the word is an excluded word, it simply leaves it alone and keeps it in the new sentence

final="" #creates an empty string to put the new words in
for j in range(0,num):
    final=final+new[j]+" "  #turns the list of new words into a string that can be printed
print(final)
```

Again, this runs perfectly, but there are some issues. Basically, I've reduced it to 4 basic problems that occur:

1) The word doesn't have a synonym but still wasn't in the excluded words list;

2) The wrong meaning of a word is entered in, or a meaning is returned that doesn't make sense in the context of the user's input;

3) The wrong tense of a verb is returned and

4) When a noun is entered, the verb of that word is returned, or vice versa (i.e. "I will grill the chicken" turns into "I will firepit the chicken" or something to that effect).

Basically, I can fix all of these problems manually by having the user go through each word that doesn't make sense, and then using nested if-else and other control structures to guide them through picking the right word, but I think this would be tedious for the user and would ruin the whole point, especially if they enter in something with a lot of words.

So basically I'm asking, which of these problems can I automate? That is to say, is there any way I can write code to get the computer to recognize any of these problems? Fixing them is the easy part, but actually getting the program to recognize the logic errors instead of making the user deal with it is the hard part.

Comment: This is a hard problem within the domain of semantic parsing. It's not going to be solvable by a few of us on SO. If you're not familiar, take a look at natural language processing and machine learning.

Comment: To check correctness of replacament you can use any software for translation of initial and changed sentance to other language. If results of translation of both sentances are the same, your replacement was correct. It is about problems (2) and (4).

Comment: You might take a look at NLTK (Natural Language ToolKit) providing [`WordNet`s](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html) which support finding synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into NLP (Natural language processing), especially POS tagging ([Part-of-speech tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging)). POS tagging will tag each word of a text corpus according to the word-category like verb, noun etc. and the grammatical form of the word. A great Python library to look into would be [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), the Natural Language Toolkit.

Here is a small example from the project's website.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> tagged[0:6]
[('At', 'IN'), ('eight', 'CD'), ("o'clock", 'JJ'), ('on', 'IN'),
('Thursday', 'NNP'), ('morning', 'NN')]
```

After tagging your sentence extract only word-categories you want to lookup synonyms for, normalize the words to present tense, do the synonym lookup and transform the result back to the correct tense and replace the desired word.

Resolving the tense of a word can also be achieved through NLP mechanisms as well as transforming words from normal form to a specific tense.